Angular command "npm install" not working
I am new to Angular and coding and just installed Angular and node.
I then created a new angular project but had the problem that it was without the app.module.ts and routing files -  which I found out is neccessary.
I found a solution for that by using the command "ng new TESTFILESNAME --no-standalone for creating a new angular project... but now the npm installazation after creating a new angular project takes like hours and wont finish.
I thought that quiting the installation and doing it manually with the command "npm install" would work but that is loading for hours as well or terminates.
Cant find a solution in the www and my brain is empty.
I also reinstalled node and angular already but I guess it is someting different.
Does somebody have a hint? :(
Versions:
Angular CLI: 17.3.4
Node: 20.12.2
NPM: 10.5.0
I also realized that I don't have these .angular and node_modules directories in my project.But I guess they will be created automatically when the project runs?


npm is not an Angular-specific program. See npm install hangs

ng new TESTFILESNAME --standalone false?, I've not find --no-standalone in the docs about ng new

If your npm command "stuck", one of the problems might be networking issue
Default npm registry address is:
https://registry.npmjs.org
You can try to ping it in terminal, if it even accessable for you:
ping registry.npmjs.org
If ping is not working then its 100% network issue and you should try to use some VPN or Cloudflare Warp

I tried ping registry.npmjs.org and it works..
